# How to use jq's match and test with character classes?

Tags: json, regex, jq

I think this should be pretty simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I can test for the containment of a literal:

```
$ echo '"f1"' | jq 'test("1")'
true
```

But I can't test for the containment of a character class (in this example, a digit):

```
$ echo '"f1"' | jq 'test("\d")'
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\d"') at <top-    level>, line 1:
test("\d")      
jq: 1 compile error
```

I'm using the release version jq-1.5.

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG I just figured it out... I need to double-escape the `\`. I'm a moron >.<

```
$ echo '"f1"' | jq 'test("\\d")'
true
```

Comment: The Google spider hasn't quite caught up with the move of RE.txt to https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Docs-for-Oniguruma-Regular-Expressions-(RE.txt)

Comment: Thanks @peak. I had thoroughly scoured the manual but didn't realize there was a wiki.

Comment: Fortunately googling 'jq faq' results in a listing with the jq FAQ at the top.  Happy scouring!